# Redis RDB backup fails on high RAM usage

Tags: debugging, redis, ram

I noticed a couple times that redis was failing to do the RDB backup on around 50%+ used RAM, as soon as I close some processes consuming a lot of RAM, it starts working again.

For example, it was failing to do the backup on 39GB used RAM but everything works fine on 25GB. Total RAM server has is 64GB

How can I debug what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://redis.io/topics/faq#background-saving-is-failing-with-a-fork-error-under-linux-even-if-i39ve-a-lot-of-free-ram

If you do not change that setting you need about twice as much ram as your datasize to be able to run the rdb backup.